# Celery Workers not doing all write transactions to database with Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am using Django with Celery. My celery worker uses Django and its models to perform database transactions. I have several tasks in my worker and each task makes read/write calls to database multiple times. I am running 6 workers, each with a concurrency of 10 threads.

The issue I am facing is that it does all `read` transactions from database correctly, but it misses doing some `write` transactions to the database. And those `write` transactions that it misses are consistent. It always fails to write to the database at the same point, though never raises any exception for it.

I have tried putting `time.sleep(5)` between transactions to give it time but no help. I am starting to think its some kind of connection pooling issue.

Does anyone else have any ideas on this or gone through same issue?

Comment: Use `transaction.atomic`?

Comment: transaction.atomic would be useful if i have to make sure that the record exists in database before it modifies anything in it. The record already exists, the issue is that its modified one field but not the other @baldr

Comment: celery task does not commit the transaction when it makes a change in it. At the end of task next task starts within the same transaction if within the same worker. You have to commit your changes explicitly. Django's connection _may_ do auto-commit, but by default it might not do it often enough. Do try `transaction.atomic` and this really could help.

Comment: @baldr even if I use model.save() method each time i want to make a change throughout the task?

Comment: `model.save()` does not commit the transaction. In Django view commit is made automatically (with Django) when the response is written back to the channel. In celery nobody cares about this and you should commit it yourself.

Comment: Ok, I'll check this